# Adding a document to another with a different document class

Tags: subfiles

Main document: `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}` (for my thesis)
Second `.tex` file: `\documentclass[twocolumn]{phdsymp}` (for my abstract)

I need this second file to be added in my main file (and the page number must continue over the second one)

When I use `\include{Abstract}` it gives errors due to the preamble that exists in the second file. I tried using `\standalone` in the main file but then it does not recognize the special commands such as `\supervisor` from the second file anymore.

Any easy fixes for this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your request is not very easy as it requires to get grid of preamble commands. It's perhaps better to include the pdf pages of the the abstract using `pdfpages` package and its `\includepdf` command

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But will this allow the page numbering to continue over the added pdf files? Since i have included pdfs already (e.g. the front page), but then there is no page numbering...

Comment: Probably not. I remember to have answered a similar question about one year ago.

Comment: I think i figured out a solution :D For anyone having the same problem, try this : \includepdf[pages={1},pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{Abstract.pdf} (it will add a page number at the bottom, if you want to have a full header and page number at the top use this: pagecommand={} )

Comment: why can you not simply input the body of the abstract without its documentclass etc, that is what I would (strongly) recommend rather than use custom include mechanisms.

Comment: Perhaps the `combine` package.